# Android: Splash Screen Issue after request storage permission

Tags: android, cordova

i'm using cordova splash screen plugin in my project
Splash screen does not work when I use these code for request storage permission:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
```

when I remove this code splash screen works again!

this is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{

boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
int res = 404; 
int code;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
....
....
....
    UiChangeListener();
    requestPermission();
}

public void UiChangeListener()
{
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
            }
        }
    });

}
private void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    } }

}

}
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
}
```

write this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
}
```

You don't have to request permission 2 times for 2 different permissions. You can combine as many permissions into single request.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the above permissions in AndroidManifest File and for creating a splash screen simply write a class like below and use intent

```
public class entercsreen extends Activity {

private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1500;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entercsreen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(entercsreen.this,MainActivity.class);
            entercsreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            entercsreen.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);





}
```

}